# ACM dropping balls

Tags: c, algorithm

Below is the code that I have copied from link http://progspedia.blogspot.com/2011/05/679-dropping-balls.html#comment-form

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t,D,I,P,i,j;
    //freopen("in.txt","r",stdin);

    while(scanf("%d",&t)==1&&t>0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d%d",&D,&I);
            P=1;D--;

            for (j=0;j<D;j++)
            {
                P= I&1 ? (P<<1) : (P<<1)+1;
                I=(I+1)>>1;
            }
            printf("%d\n",P);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code runs perfectly but I don't understand how this code keeps tracks of the thing that which sub tree we have to go after level 1. If someone helps me in that that would be very helpful for me.

Link to the problem is http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=620

Comment: If you don't understand then you probably shouldn't have copied it ;-) As shown this does nothing, you would need to include the line that opens the file and ensure *in.txt* contains valid input for the problem.

Comment: You should really figure this out yourself. Do you understand the problem? Do you understand how to solve it on paper? If so (and if you want to use the copied code) fire up a debugger, see what is done with the input and how this corresponds with your understanding of what should happen. But the best would be for you to solve the problem first.

Answer (score 1):

`P` tracks the specific node (and therefore the subtree)

The traversal decision is made here.

```
            P= I&1 ? (P<<1) : (P<<1)+1;
```